# distribute m pennies to n people, what is the expectation of coins one would obtain

Tags: probability

Assume there are $m$ pennies and $n$ people. We want to distribute the pennies to the people by uniformly picking a vector $(x_1,...,x_n)$ from the set of all vectors satisfying $x_1+...+x_n=m$, where $x_i$ is the number of coins given to person $i$.

What is the expectation of the number of pennies given to player 1?

Some analysis: I figured out that, the probability for getting a large $x_1$ is lower when compared to a smaller value of $x_1$, although the solution is uniformly picked. I guess, every person has the same likelihood to get the a certain number of coins, which means no one has an advantage. Therefore the expectation for player 1 is just $m\over n$ Is my analysis and answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, you are using symmetry.  Here is another approach.

Suppose the pennies are distinguishable.  Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_m$ each be random variables, with $X_i=1$ if penny $i$ is given to person 1, and $X_i=0$ if penny $i$ is not given to person 1.  We have $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{n}$, and $E(X_1+\cdots+X_m)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_m)=\frac{m}{n}$, where the linearity of expectation is used in the first equality.  Note that $E(X_1+\cdots+X_m)$ denotes the expected total number of pennies person 1 receives.

Comment: O, but does it make no differences between distinguishable and indistinguishable, also is it also correct to do it in this way? Let $X_i$ be the random variable person i get. Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_i=m$ since there should be no any pennies left. Then $E(\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_i)=E(m)=m$ and since $E(X_i)=E(X_j)$ for all $i\ne j$ so $E(\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}E(X_1)=m$ and hence $E(X_1)=\frac{m}{n}$